# Ford Figo 1.4 TDCI 2010 Ambient turbo not boosting

Tags: ford, troubleshooting, diesel

I got a Ford Figo 1.4 TDCI 2010 Ambient I just had the turbo repaired I've had turbo checked and its fine but it still won't boost we've checked everything from valves to EGR to MAF everything is fine no fault codes I just honestly don't understand

Answer (score 0):

Faulty fuel injector seals can cause this problem on the Ford 1.4, since they are very sensitive.  [Some people report](https://www.honestjohn.co.uk/forum/post/index.htm?t=107887) that the seals can be replaced, while others replace the entire injector.